# How to Upload Any file from internal or External Storage in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have written code for Picking Image & Uploading Image and getting a particular image with it's location in emulator but how do i access any file from Android File System using Xamarin so what should i use to do that ?.

```
namespace XAFileUpload_2._0
{
    [Activity(Label = "XAFileUpload 2.0", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        //Pick Id to know the pick item no.
        public static readonly int PickImageId = 1000;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Browse);
            button.Click += BrowseButtonOnClick;

        }

        void BrowseButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArs)
        {
            Intent = new Intent();
            Intent.SetType("image/*");
            Intent data = Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

            try
            {
                StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Error occured ", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
            {
                UploadFile(data);

            }
        }

        void UploadFile(Intent data)
        {
            ICursor cursor = null;

            try
            {
                Button upButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Upload);

                // assuming image
                var docID = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(data.Data);
                var id = docID.Split(':')[1];
                var whereSelect = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Id + "=?";
                var projections = new string[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
                // Try internal storage first
                cursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.InternalContentUri, projections, whereSelect, new string[] { id }, null);
                if (cursor.Count == 0)
                {
                    // not found on internal storage, try external storage
                    cursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, projections, whereSelect, new string[] { id }, null);
                }
                var colData = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                var fullPathToImage = cursor.GetString(colData);
                string fpti = cursor.GetString(colData);

                string address = "http://192.168.3.157:82/Values/DownFile";


                upButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                        progressDialog.SetTitle("Please wait...");
                        progressDialog.SetCancelable(false);

                        Task.Run(() =>
                        {

                            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {
                                progressDialog.Show();
                            });

                            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                            {
                                client.UploadFile(address, fullPathToImage);

                            }

                            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {

                                progressDialog.Dismiss();

                                string msg = "Upload Completed";
                                Toast.MakeText(this, msg, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                            });
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error("MediaPath", ex.Message);
                    }
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("MediaPath", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                cursor?.Close();
                cursor?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [following](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6990/how-to-correctly-save-and-read-files):

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string filename = Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
}

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent = new Intent();
            Intent.SetType("image/*");
            Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
```

It opens image pickup dialog and after choosing an image it automatically calls OnActivityResult method

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
        //Your code to upload image. 
        //image uri is in data object.
        }
    }
```